# Install packages locally in golang module feature

Tags: go

When I install a package using go get, in the golang module mode, these are installed in the go root folder.

I would like to be able to install the modules in the same way that npm or yarn does for node.js, global or local.

what would be the right way to achieve this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Go is not NodeJS. What are you actually trying to accomplish (i.e. why are you looking for different behavior)?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I know that go is not node.js but the modules feature was created to mimic the feature of package managers like npm, yarn, etc and that works correctly for me, but I want each of my projects to have their dependencies in their workspace.

Comment: All the dependencies of all my projects are installed in C:\Users\[user]\go\pkg, this is disastrous to be managed correctly.

Surely it is because of my lack of experience in this new feature, but I want to know what would be the correct way to perform this behavior.

Comment: Why is that disastrous? It caches each version independently, so it's not like it will break something if different projects use different versions. If they use the same version, they'll get the same code. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Get used to it. there is nothing wrong with how it is done.

Comment: @Adrian Of course I understand, but if I have multiple projects I will have a quantity of "garbage", as I delete the data that corresponds to each project in a simple way. I am working offline, Should I create a bash script to eliminate each dependency?, or what is the correct way to eliminate the dependencies that I no longer require that exist on my computer, (go get) does not have a functionality to remove dependencies :(

Comment: No, `go get` is for getting things, not deleting them. See `go help clean`.

Comment: @Adrian haha, thanks for your time Adrian, I'm going to investigate what I can do with go clean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can create your module files like this:

```
go mod init [import path]
```

After that you can run this command any time to move all dependencies into the `vendor` directory:

```
go mod vendor
```

This is very similar to the behaviour of the `node_modules` directory.
To build using the dependencies in this directory, you can add `-mod vendor` to your build command:

```
go build -mod vendor
```

This way you can copy your project to any machine without go-getting anything on that other machine.

According to the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/mod#vendoring), the `-mod=vendor` flag is set automatically if the Go version in the `go.mod` file is `1.14` or higher and a `vendor` directory exists.

To clean unused dependencies from the `vendor` directory, you can run

```
go mod tidy
```

Answer (score 2):

There is little bit different approach. Go lock versions based on github (gitlab, etc) current commit. When you want to use specific versions of packages and not master all the time you want to use go modules (this is official way to do it, but there are some other tools). You init module in you project

```
go mod init [possible custom package name]
```

And everytime you call "go get somepackage" it writes versions it uses to a file called `go.mod`.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm already using that mode "golang Modules", the problem is that the modules are installed in C: \Users\[user]\go\pkg, and I want them to be installed locally in my workspace.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunatelly official way is to use go modules. There are unofficial tools which downloads deps to the project under vedndor, .vendor or other dir, but they are all deprecated in favor of go modules.