# golang cannot find module for local path

Tags: go, import, package

I want to push out some of API, from main package into separate package:

```
myapp/
    main.go
    myapi/
        myapi.go
```

Inside `main.go` i have

```
package main

import "./myapi"

...
```

And `myapi.go` just starts with:

```
package myapi

...
```

When I am trying to run main, it seems like it can't find my `myapi` `#include`. It gives me following error:

```
D:\go\myapp> go run .
build _/D_/go/myapp/myapi: cannot find module for path _/D_/go/myapp/myapi
```

I came from C/C++ world, and it's extremely unobvious, how to include from subfolder in golang. Could you help me with this?

Comment: [Do not use relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go).

Comment: You can use a module file that defines the name of your module and its submodules

Comment: @xarantolus How? Given above sample program, what actions should I perform?

Comment: @xakepp35: What is non-sense? Using the Go as intended?

Comment: @xakepp35 you should run `go mod init your.domain/somename` in your package root (`myapp`), it will create a file called `go.mod`. Now you can import `your.domain/somename/myapi` to access your package. When you move the root folder somewhere else, you can still build it. You could even build it without downloading packages on another pc by [vendoring your dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58697521)

Comment: @xarantolus `gcc` is always on the system, so in my imaginary nuclear disaster, i can fallback using it. So here goes my that upper question.. Can golang be like so? Local only! Or.. would it require constant internet connection, thus unusable by profesional devs?

Comment: After you set up the module (the name is usually a domain, but the build process won't try to connect to it; it's just a name), you can run `go mod vendor` in your root directory to download all dependencies. As I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700267), it is possible to use go completely offline after you downloaded your dependencies

Comment: @xakepp35: Bad analogy. A better analogy would be when someone asks "How do I use a bazooka to kill a fly?" and the answer is "Don't use a bazooka to kill a fly."

Answer (score 4):

Go uses something called Module Paths. These are paths that identify your packages. They are not necessarily related to the file system.

An example of a module path is `github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten`.

If you're using Go modules, this is also the path Go automatically downloads it from.

If you're using $GOPATH, the path into the source of the module would be `go/src/github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten`.

Initialize your module with a new module path using `go mod init <module path>`. Generally this will be your GitHub repository, without the `https://`. This will allow for both your and others code to be able accessible using that module path. `myapi` should then be accessible via `import "github.com/username/repo/myapi"`.

If you still wish to use the old $GOPATH method, simply place your code inside `go/src/<module path>`. The method of accessing `myapi` is equivalent.

Read [Using Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) and [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for expla, i've upvoted your effort. For me, as a man of 20y of programming experience, golang is like C with some influences. Like Borland's one(Currently, Embarcadero) modules experience. And C.. But that was a real good thing(if you've used to know things like Delphi 7, or latter RAD) - that allowed us not to bother with global stuff. It's like you may define some local module, that is just within your subfolder, and use it with ease.

Comment: If you've survived a nuclear war, and you're using Go, you'll still use Go as it's designed.